# Do CEVIANS in Triangles divides the emerging angle in the same ratio as they do to the opposite side .

Tags: triangles, area, angle, ratio, median

Ok I know that suppose in a triangle **ABC** , there's a cevian AD intersecting BC at D and dividing it in the ratio **4:5** so which implies that it divides Area of Triangle also in ratio 4:5 by that cevian. **My Question is Do this Cevian divides angle A in the same ratio** .

Comment: If this was true, then trisection of an angle using a ruler and a compass would be an easy (rather than impossible) operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider say an equilateral triangle and the median from its vertex, you have a situation in which the ratio 1:1 holds both for the side and the angle. But then, keeping the foot of the median fixed, you can slightly turn your side around that point. One of the halves gets bigger and the other one gets smaller, so the ratio is not preserved, although you are preserving the ratio 1:1 for the angles.

Conclusion: the property does not hold.